# Таблица друзей в базе данных

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Как лучше всего составить таблицу друзей `tb_friend` в базе данных. Основной запрос, который будет использоваться, это - является ли `user1` другом `user2` или наоборот.

Comment: Пользователь **user1** находиться в сестеме как зарегистрированный юзер, тогда по **user1** и наоборот. У них могут быть и разные друзья.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна отдельная таблица, которая будет связывать `id` одного с `id` другого. Соответственно два внешних ключа на основную таблицу.